# How to smoothly impute values in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, quandl

I am doing a data science project using **Streamlit**, **Pandas** and the [**Quandl Nasdaq Nordic  Dataset**](https://www.quandl.com/data/NASDAQOMX/NOMXNEN-NASDAQ-OMX-Nordic-Energy-NOMXNEN).

When I use the Python Quandl module to get the data and plot it on a `streamlit.area_chart` or `streamlit.line_chart`, it seemed to have some missing values or ones that dropped to 0. I wanted to impute these, but whether I used `"mean"` or `median`, the imputed data then had wide flat sections.

###### Here is a zoom in on the flat areas

[image: Zoom in on Flat Areas on My Graph]

I obviously don't want this. Is there any other way of imputing values with **pandas**, **sklearn** `SimpleImputer`, or any other resource, so that it preserves the trend in the imputes?

A suggestion I have could be taking an average from the surrounding rows, like a moving average, but I am not sure how to implement this or if this is the best way.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are many ways to impute, I'm not sure what you're looking for. I think you want something like an ARIMA model but that seems a bit much to 'generate' data (both stretching the truthfulness of the data and in what you're looking for). Basically, how do you know that the value didn't move differently from how you expect? What if it went down instead of doing a repeated hill? The other methods in [`pd.DataFrame.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) might be of some use, but this kind of interpolation is iffy.

Comment: I am not generating data, but predicting it. Do you know if the data should suddenly just cut out? It is an amateur project, so does not need to be overly accurate.

Comment: Without the imputed values, there are no values. Just np.nan

Comment: I first thought weather data, but it looks like some kind of financial data. Financial data generally moves with a random walk and is inherently unpredictable.

Comment: I have looked at the `interpolate` methods. It looks good. Testing now... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **ifly6**, I have found the solution.

Simply set your dataset to the interpolated version as below:

```
data = df.interpolate()
```

#### Simple!